# Logentries with heroku not displaying Exceptions

Tags: heroku, logging, logentries

I'm very new to logentries and still learning. I'm using logentries with heorku.

I used to see a list of Exceptions but now it constantly says "0" even with there are plenty.

What can I do for logentries to show me an aggregated view of the exceptions.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Logentries has been [removed](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/logentries) by Heroku Addons.

These are the alternatives you can try

- If you want to use heroku addon only, you can use [logtail](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/logtail)
- Otherway, you can use [logentries directly](https://logentries.com/) without using heroku addon.

Thanks